User Profile Service Sync 2019 not syncing
I'm having issues setting up the User Profile Service sync, a screenshot of what I see

I can connect to AD and view containers etc

However, every time I try to sync, nothing seems to populate; i.e., I get the same screen shown in the first screenshot.
I've reviewed the event logs and can see no errors associated with the User Profile.
I've checked the following post found here, but all went quite
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1431636/cannot-sync-users-to-user-profile-service-in-share
Any help or pointers would be much appreciated. Thanks
